# How to make custom curvy UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I want to create custom curvy `UISlider` as like below screen which is fit to screen.

[image]

I checked [MTCircularSlider](https://github.com/EranBoudjnah/MTCircularSlider) library and also apply of `tranform` animaton to UISlider control but none of them working.
My mind got stuck after performing many tries.

Thank you

Comment: what problem are you facing with MTCircularSlider ?

Comment: It will not expand the slider in full screen

Comment: i think you could create MTCircularSlider in different size. Is it possible? If so, try to create with Screen size & customize the library

Comment: Yes i already tried to customize but can't getting idea from where should i have to change the code

Comment: From what I quickly read of the doc: Use `trackMinAngle()` and `trackMaxAngle()`. seems to be what you need. Set the slider as "big", find the angle corresponding of when the slider touch the borders of you view (screen in your case).

Comment: @Larme What do you mean by  Set the slider as "big"?

Comment: "as like below screen which is fit to screen." Could you be more specific? Do you mean that you see all the slider (circle) on the screen, or that some part is hidden?

Comment: @Larme As you can see in screen, I want to display as semi circle which is fit to screen width

Comment: So you need to set a frame for your `MTCircularSlider` with bigger width that your screen width. Is that your issue?

Comment: @Larme yes, Exactly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164074/discussion-between-larme-and-superman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MTCircularSlider library

```
fileprivate var controlRadius: CGFloat {
     return min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2.0 - controlThickness
 }
```

See above this library uses `min` value from width and height.

So, You need to maintain your view width, because it's depend on minimum value of View. 
You can mange your view by leading and trailing according below screenshot[image]

or either you can use by proportionalWidth constrain to 0.80 of your superview

And also set the trackAngle as below

[image]